# Unable to ref to another schema: Cannot resolve the name 'xs:schema' to a(n) 'element declaration' component

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, xsd

I have re-created a SOAP webservice based on an existing wsdl file in reference to the guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-soap-web-service.
The original wsdl is residing on a .NET environment, while I need to reproduce the same response from a Java environment using spring-boot web-service.

I have no issues for the simple response returning simple data type such as int. But for complex response returning DataSet (from .NET), I'm unable to re-create the proper classes. It may relate the to the error below encountered in eclipse workspace:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
> - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xs:schema' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
> - src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:schema'. It was detected that 'xs:schema' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this
> namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///C:/03_PROJECTS/ws/src/main/resources/schema/abc.xsd'. If this is the incorrect
> namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'xs:schema' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///C:/03_PROJECTS/ws/src/main/resources/schema/abc.xsd'.

Below is the schema details for the xsd file:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.net/abc/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

And below is the sample snipped element that gets the error:

```
<xs:element name="GetProdItemDescriptionsResponse">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
            name="GetProdItemDescriptionsResult">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="xs:schema"/>
                    <xs:any />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Please advise why the referencing to another schema is throwing an error. I believe the response for this should be a DataSet as menitoned before. Just wanted to know if there's an issue with the xsd file or if this is possible in Java or if there's a possible workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSD file contains an element reference which refers to the *XSD schema*. That's unusual, but not wrong. The element content seems to be a snippet of XML schema. I suspect that you need to add an `<xs:import>` to your XSD file so that it can locate the XSD that describes XSDs.

You *could* do that as follows:

- download the 'schema for schema' from the W3C web site
- add a `schemaLocation` attribute to your XSD as a hint to your XML processor

However, you should be able to add an 'entity resolver' in your Spring environment which will allow the Spring XML processor to locate the XSD via its URL.

Before you ask...I don't know why .Net did not report this error, but it's possible that .Net auto-resolves the schema-for-schema.